# How to unhide WPF window from another process?

Tags: c#, wpf, process

I have WPF program that needs to be hided (not close) when pressing the 'X' button.

In parallel, there is a c# program that on a certain button needs to unhide it.

Hiding the WPF program works perfectly.
Problem is, when trying to unhide it from the other c# process, the WPF window is shown black (as if the form itself still hidden while window is shown).

Any ideas?

Tried the change the flags on ShowWindow() function, no help.
Tried not to hide the WPF window but change the visibility, same result.

WPF code for hiding the main window:

```
void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    Hide();

}
```

c# code:

```
var myHandle= UIWin32.FindWindow(null, "My title");
UIWin32.ShowWindow(myHandle, UIWin32.Win32Flags.SW_SHOW);
UIWin32.ShowWindow(myHandle, UIWin32.Win32Flags.SW_RESTORE);
UIWin32.SetForegroundWindow(myHandle);
```

Answer (score 0):

After `ShowWindow` you can use [MoveWindow](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.movewindow) function with Redraw flag like this:

```
MoveWindow(handle,0,0,width,height,true);
```

Signature:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr handle, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool redraw);
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the reference source for [Window.Hide()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Window.cs,224) it appears that Hide both sets the window's `Visibility` property to `Visibility.Hidden` and hides the window's source window with a `ShowWindow(..., SW_HIDE`).

Using `ShowWindow(myHandle, SW_HIDE)` does shows the source window but the `Visibility` property is still `Visibility.Hidden`, which would be why nothing draws.  Nothing in the `Window` class seems to check for the window being re-shown externally.

However the `Window` class will react to the `WM_ACTIVATE` message that `SetForegroundWindow()` will generate; it will invoke the [`OnActivated()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.onactivated?view=netframework-4.8) method when that happens.  So the following code will reset the `Visibility` on the WPF window when it is activated:

```
protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnActivated(e);
    Show();
}
```